# spring boot 1.4 unable to find the location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, spring-boot-admin

I put the path for jks file in application.yml

```
ssl:
   trustStorePath: keystore/pas_ist.jks
```

and reading this like

```
 @Value("${ssl.trustStorePath}") String trustStorePath
```

Its working fine in spring boot 1.3 , but not working in 1.4 , getting the error like this

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: keystore/pas_ist.jks
```

But the file is there and working in spring boot 1.3 with no issues and not working in spring boot 1.4

Comment: It seems that you're using a relative path. Are you certain that your `user.dir` is the same in both applications? It looks like something environmental is different. You may want to check Spring Boot admin endpoint `/env.json` to take a look at your full config in both sides and find where's the difference.

Comment: In Spring boot 1.4 the jar structure is changed

Comment: can you post the output of your jar listing?

Comment: Hi Chris i use the following jars                                                                                                                    org.springframework:spring-tx, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot, spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.2.3.RELEASE,

Comment: spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:1.2.3.RELEASE','spring-context', version: '4.2.8.RELEASE',spring-boot-starter-web',spring-boot-starter-ws',:spring-boot-starter',spring-boot-starter-security',

Comment: 'hibernate-core', version:'5.1.0.Final',beanio', version: '2.0.7', 'xmlschema-core', version: '2.0.1', 'ehcache-core', version: '2.5.1', 'bonecp', version:0.8.0.RELEASE','httpcore', version: '4.4.5', 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2', 'spring-ws-support', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE',

Comment: It's not clear from where you expect the `keystore/pas_ist.jks` file to be loaded or how you are running your application. It's also not clear what's throwing the `FileNotFoundException` as you haven't shared the stack trace. Can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable, example](/help/mcve) of your problem? If you are using Tomcat you may be experiencing a side-effect of [this change](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56777).

Comment: public DataSource pasDatasource(     @Value("${ssl.trustStorePath}") String trustStorePath ){
DB2SimpleDataSource dataSource = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
  dataSource.setSslConnection(true);
  dataSource.setSslTrustStoreLocation(trustStorePath);
  dataSource.setSslTrustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);
}

Comment: I am Reading like this and using the .jks file here . I am getting the FileNotFoundException  in Spring boot 1.4 and working fine in 1.3

Comment: It got Resolved by using the following code                                                                                        `ClassLoader classLoader = this.class.getClassLoader();
  File trustoreFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("keystore/pas_ist.jks").getFile());`       and reading using like this  `dataSource.setSslTrustStoreLocation(trustoreFile.getAbsolutePath());`